# Is 'words' a method?

Tags: python, attributes

Working on this chatbot tutorial (https://apps.worldwritable.com/tutorials/chatbot/), I'm stuck at the first base... It's probably a very beginner mistake like, sorry.

So I put this code in Ipython :

---

```
GREETING_KEYWORDS = ("hello", "hi", "greetings", "sup", "what's up",)

GREETING_RESPONSES = ["'sup bro", "hey", "nods", "hey you get my snap?"]

def check_for_greeting(sentence): 
      for word in sentence.words: 
            if word.lower() in GREETING_KEYWORDS: 
                   return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
```

---

And then call it with :

---

```
import numpy as np 
phrase = ["hello"] 
np_phrase = np.array(phrase) 
check_for_greeting(np_phrase)
```

---

Also tried with different types but always the same answer : 'x' object has no attribute 'words'

Is 'words' a method? How does it work?

Thank you so much in advance, I've been looking for the answer for a long time now, I promise.

Comment: I think you just mean `for word in sentence`. It's probably just a typo in the tutorial?

Comment: No, `words` is not called, so it is not a method. It is merely an attribute. You are passing in an object `sentence` that has no such attribute.

Comment: Oh, actually, probably not a typo in the tutorial... they're passing something different in (a `TextBlob`).

Comment: But your code so far should work if you just use `for word in sentence`.

Comment: @GhostCat: the tutorial doesn't include the numpy code posted here, but does describe how the bot does some preprocessing before calling the function.

Comment: sentence does not have "words", i.e. empty or not valid collection type for sentence

Comment: Yes I was missing TextBlob and did not see the code simplification. So cool to move forward. Thanks @smarx

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyHorne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually when you loop over a list or in this case a ﻿﻿numpy.ndarray you would address it how you define it.

In this case you set sentence and you loop over words. This will not work in this example, that said we cannot see all the code for that chatbot.

If I do below it will print 'found it' but it will not print a random response, I suspect that random.choice is a function somewhere in the script I cannot see.

```
def check_for_greeting(sentence):
print type(sentence)
for word in sentence:
    if word.lower() in GREETING_KEYWORDS:
        print "Found it"
        return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
```

I hope this help.

Comment: That helps just great. Thank you 

Answer (score 3):

You missed something crucial in the tutorial:

```
parsed = TextBlob(cleaned)
```

and that object is then passed to the `check_for_greeting()` function:

```
resp = check_for_greeting(parsed)
```

It is the instance of `TextBlob` that has a [`words` attribute](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#textblob.blob.BaseBlob.words). The tutorial actually teaches you about that object, linking to the [project documentation](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/):

> Python programmers working with NLP have two great high-level libraries to choose from: `TextBlob` and `spaCy`. `spaCy` is easy to use and fast, though it can be memory intensive and doesn’t attempt to cover the whole of statistical NLP. `TextBlob` wraps the sprawling NLTK library in a very approachable API, so while it can be slower, it’s quite comprehensive. I’ll use `TextBlob` here, though see my article on text generation for an example using spaCy.

If you want to use the same code locally, you'll either have to use `TextBlob` too, *or* adjust the function to treat `sentence` as a sequence of words (removing the `.words` attribute).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I'll dive into TextBlob. 'can't wait to pursue.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Note that you can mark only *one* of the answers as accepted, not both. Which one is entirely up to you; pick the one that you feel helped you most, or by whatever criteria you feel apply. Not picking either is a valid option too.